# QML: How do you toggle boolean?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk, qml

In QML, how do you toggle boolean non explicitly?

For example:

Whenever a button is pressed, a boolean property will simply switch to its other value.

If false, it will be come true.

If true, it will become false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's a magic method for QML/Qt, but I usually just use a "toggle_it" function in python that looks something like:

```
def toggle_it_cb(the_bool):
  the_bool = not the_bool
  return the_bool

my_bool = False
my_bool = toggle_it_cb(my_bool)
print(my_bool)
my_bool = toggle_it_cb(my_bool)
print(my_bool)
```

It could be done better if it were a class attribute.  No need to return to assign, etc.

Almost every language ever has a negation operator (usually !() or similar).

Comment: my_bool = toggle_it_cb(my_bool) was the key here. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Using just JavaScript:

```js
OnClicked {
    checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked
}
```

Comment: onClicked: two.enabled = !two.enabled was what worked for me. I am not sure where your code is supposed to go, because it gave me an error, "Unexpected ;"